# How to pass props to an object (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know about props in React and how to pass props but I'm struggling to pass props to a Component that is just an object.

VideoGameList.js

```
const VideoGameList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Fire Emblem Engage",
    releaseDate: "01/20/2023",
    price: 59.99,
    quantity: 0,
  },
];
```

My `VideoGameList` component is holding this array that is just an object of newly released video games. Inside each object is a `quantity` value that will increase from a function in another component.

VideoGame.js

```
const VideoGame = () => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);

  const addToCart = () => {
    setQuantity(quantity + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div>
        {VideoGameList.map(
          ({ title, releaseDate, price, quantity }, index) => (
            <div>
              <img key={src} src={src} alt={title} />
              <div>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p>{releaseDate}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>${price}</p>
                <button onClick={addToCart}>
                  Add to Cart
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Inside this component you'll notice a few things. The first is I'm using the map method to display each video game in its own div. Inside the div is a picture of the game cover, the price, the release date and I have the quantity. My `addToCart` function increases the useState of quantity and I have a button with an `onClick` to increase it.

My problem is I can't seem to figure out how to use the addToCart function from my VideoGame component to increase the `quantity` in my VideoGameList component. The reason I'm doing this is because I have another page that will only show games that have a quantity of > 0. Please advice.

Comment: You should initialize a videoGameList state on the parent component. Then pass the list to this component to render it. See props here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html. Then you can also pass a callback function to send an event to the parent component, see https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. There is also a problem with the add to cart function: replace `onClick={addToCart}` by `onClick={() => addToCart(id)}`. Then you can try to modify your videoGameList accordingly

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been looking more into this but haven't gotten it yet. One thing I don't understand is why you need to use an arrow function for the onClick.

Comment: because onClick is of type function, so you have to pass a function to it, here a function with no parameters